# Executing a process normally from an elevated one

Tags: windows, winapi, uac

Is there some way to launch a process in non-elevated way from an elevated one. My setup is launched elevated and when it finalizes, it will just launch the main application. Because the setup is elevated, the main process will be elevated as well which is not desirable. What is the best solution to this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206646/create-a-process-with-ordinary-rights-from-an-administrator-process .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a problem, Vista/Win7 don't appear to have an API to obtain the unprivileged user token you need to call CreateProcessAsUser().  The only solutions I've found involve using the task scheduler to launch the program.  That doesn't strike me as very practical.

An easy solution that jumps to mind is to use a small non-elevated helper process.  It can in turn launch the elevated setup process and wait for a confirmation from that one to launch the non-elevated one.  The handshake is simple enough to do this with a named mutex.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this without hacks is to have two processes (Can be implemented in the same .exe)

Instance A starts Instance B with ShellExecute and the runas verb.
B does the installing, when its time to start your app on the "finish page", it uses some form of inter processes communication (RPC, shared memory+events etc) with A telling it to start a process on its behalf.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a nice way to do it, provided you don't care about situations where the Shell is not running (e.g. possibly some Terminal Services application-only setups, perhaps, though I'm not sure):

http://brandonlive.com/2008/04/27/getting-the-shell-to-run-an-application-for-you-part-2-how/

It gets an interface to Explorer.exe, which should be running in the user's normal context, and asks Explorer to execute a command in its behalf. This is done just using simple, documented COM interfaces and without having to mess around with process tokens or code/DLL injection.