# Java Project admin privileges windows 7

Tags: java, netbeans, file-permissions

I am building a swing application (a file explorer) that has to copy/move files/folders around. When I try to copy to some folders such as Program Files, it throws an exception (access denied). I can solve by running NetBeans as administrator.

Is there anyway I can give admin rights to my project only, without running the whole Virtual Machine as admin?

Comment: read this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206646/create-a-process-with-ordinary-rights-from-an-administrator-process

Comment: I need it the other way around, i am not running the VM as admin, although i need my project to run as admin, i was thinking maybe change something in Project Properties under run...is that possible?

Comment: Use "Run As" to start your program as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You could, for a really horrible non-cross-platform method, use VBScript's `.ShellExecute` and `Runtime.exec` to force a program to run as an administrator.

For brevity's sake, I have created a simple program available at
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/26746878/Misc/JavaElevated.zip

It can be run with `java Launcher`.

From NetBeans, I'd assume you'd somehow get it to run the `Launcher` as the main class instead of the main `Program`.

Answer (score -2):

Is there not a command line startup, I'm sure there is and that there is a guy(ette) out there who would write it out for us in about 10 hot seconds. Windows 7/64

Comment: This does not clearly answer the OPs question.  Please put comments in the comment section.