# Run code as non-administrator

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8.1, user-permissions

I am writing code that calls the [IApplicationActivationManager interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706902(v=vs.85).aspx) to open a windows store app.

I get the error:

```
"[Name of App] can't run while File Explorer is running with Administrator privileges..."
```

It is essential that I launch my app as a non administrator. I also don't control the administrator context that the code that calls the .exe I will create uses. So, two questions:

**Can I (by changing the project settings or something) debug as a non-administrator?**

**Can I force my exe to run as a non administrator? (when it's out in the wild)**

C4ud3x helpfully points out that this can be added to the app.manifest. This is true, but unfortunately it will still run as administrator if the invoker lets it (it is in fact the default value). It also looks like asInvoker is the [lowest value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ad1fshk.aspx).

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

edit:
fine I accept the only answer to the first question is don't run visual studios as admin. Thanks for all your help with that.

Comment: I thought the default was that the debuggee ISN'T run as admin?

Comment: I don't understand what is stopping you. Can you elaborate what is the problem?

Comment: Please provide more information. Important parts are for example the MS Windows Version used and if UAC is enabled. If the latter is the case and you do not demand administrator privileges in you manifest file the programm should run w/o administrator privileges.

Comment: If you launch your debugger as an admin, you launch your app as an admin... So you shouldn't run your debugger as an admin to start with... (If you launch any process from a process that runs as admin, you run that new process as admin as well, there's no way to ride down that elevator.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a process with ordinary rights from an administrator process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206646/create-a-process-with-ordinary-rights-from-an-administrator-process)

Comment: Note, though, that if the end user is logged in with the built-in Administrator account (or has UAC turned off) there's nothing you can do.  Windows Store won't run in those cases, you'll just have to show an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project-explorer expand 'properties' and open your 'app.manifest'.
You can add this line there:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

'AsInvoker' means the application is started with the permission-level from the user whos logged in.

This line should already be auto-generated and commented out in your manifest.

**Edit:**
Aaah, wait. You need to run as a non-admin while DEBUGGING??? Dont know how the permissions behave in debugging-mode.